# How to change the way the date is displayed in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to permanently remove the the day and month from the date but keep the year. This is for WordPress 4.8.1 running Culture theme.

In other words; when I, in the future, write and publish a post, only the YEAR will be shown on the blogpage (frontpage) and on the single post view.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? If you show us the code you are using to display the date, we can give you some pointers. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I seriously doubt that you really want to alter the dates in the underlying database to only have a numerical year.  Your question should be a presentation thing only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function and modify it according to your requirement

```
function my_project_filter_publish_dates( $the_date, $d, $post ) {
return date( 'Y', strtotime( $the_date ) );
}
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'my_project_filter_publish_dates', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Where do I place that function?

Within which file and where?

Comment: It is my pleasure hope you get your requirement

Comment: I added your function to my themes functions.php but nothing changed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you using  get the date function to display

Comment: I change the hook now please check

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please inform me where to put what and I'll give it a go.

Comment: No, still the same. Do I put all that code into functions.php = 

function my_project_filter_publish_dates( $the_date, $d, $post ) {
return date( 'Y', strtotime( $the_date ) );
}
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'my_project_filter_publish_dates', 10, 3 );

Comment: @BjornenNilsson This is why we need to see the code you are using before we can help you with your specific issue :) Can you update your question with information about how you are currently displaying the date?

Comment: I have no code. I have a theme and I need code for that theme/for wordpress so that only the year is shown for already existing posts and for future post.

Comment: I did. There's a section there called;

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# FROM HERE YOU CAN ADD YOUR OWN FUNCTIONS
#-----------------------------------------------------------------# 


I put it all there. No change.

Comment: my code is working fine i have tested it today. in your post listing how you display the date share that code with us if you are not using get_the_date function to display the date than my code with not work.

Comment: It's funny. None of you thought of just changing the date setting in WP admin to " Y " by using custom.

And no, your code did not work on my site. 
I had to use:

.blog-content-box .entry-header .date-auth-wrap .date {display:none;}

if I wanted the date gone altogether. None of you asked for the URL either.

Anyway. It's fixed.